# --user=root doesn't seem to override fabric env.user, how come?

Tags: fabric

I have a fabfile with:

```
env.user = 'deploy'

def infra():
    """You need to use a user that can root itself, deploy cannot without a
    password."""
    put('conf.d/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.foo.hk',
         '/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.foo.hk', use_sudo=True)
     sudo('nginx -s reload',)
```

Which I run like `fab infra -Rservers`.

So I thought I could override the user with `--user=root or -u root` when I run `fab infra --user=root` but it's still asking me for a password. However if I change `env.user` to `env.user = 'root'` it doesn't. I can also use the settings context manager like:

```
def infra(user):
    """You need to use a user that can root itself, deploy cannot without a
    password."""
    with settings(user=user):
        put('conf.d/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.foo.hk',
             '/etc/nginx/sites-available/www.foo.hk', use_sudo=True)
        sudo('nginx -s reload',)
```

That works when I do `fab infra:root -Rservers`. So clearly it's possible to override the setting, but it seems like I can't from the normal command line flag. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what version of fabric are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to override the default setting from the command line in the way I would want. There's a ticket for it though https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/680 and it seem like it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a [ticket open for this](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/680), I also showed the example there more like you showed here. My guess is you can't set env.user in the file beforehand as that's an explicit hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
fab infra:hosts=root@somehost
```

It's unclear to me whether the same `username@...` pattern works with roles or roledefs.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.2.0/usage/execution.html

Comment: I can't specify host on the command line because they are ever changing. It seems like you can't do this: https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/680